# Testing on iOS 3.1 simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

iOS project. Base SDK 4.2, deployment target 3.0. A customer is complaining about an issue on iOS 3.1 (he has an old device).

I tried installing Xcode 3.2.3 - the oldest there is for download. It does not offer iOS 3.1 as a test target. Does anyone know how can I enable older versions of iOS on the simulator?

The box also has Xcode 4 (in a different folder). Could it be the case that they're sharing the iOS simulator, and the backwards-incompatible one from Xcode 4 is getting in the way?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you to get/loan a device with iOS3.1 for testing the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/old-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html

Some of the links are dead though. Apple is removing those old files little by little. Get them while supplies last.

Answer (score 2):

There is no substitute for testing on a real device.

I've had a problem with my iPod touch (3rd gen, ios 5.0) crashing in one app. Every day. The dev won't buy, beg, borrow or steal a real iPod touch to test it on so he can fix it. As a user this is extremely frustrating.

**EDIT:**

The final versions of Xcode with the iPhone SDK, as it was called then, are not available from Apple's download page, but the direct links still work.

The direct links can be found at:
http://chris-fletcher.com/2010/08/28/howto-install-iphone-sdk-2-0-3-1-for-xcode-3-2/

Comment: While true, does not answer my question. Besides, it's a perfectly reproducible crash at app startup - my experience tells me it will crash on the simulator, as well.

Comment: I was able to find Xcode 3.2.1 (10.6) or 3.1.4 (10.5) which should have the iPhone 3.1.3 SDK (as it was called then) on Apple's developer web site: <developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action>; I had to go to page 5 of 7 to find this.

Comment: You will also need an older OS version to install this on as Xcode 3.x isn't supported on 10.7+.

Comment: I see it now, but it's called "Xcode 3.2.1" as opposed to "Xcode and iOS SDK". I'll download and try anyway... EDIT: no, it's just Xcode. No iOS there.

Comment: There used to be separate downloads for Xcode and Xcode + iPhone SDK so this might not have it. I'm kind of doubting it by the small size of the download. This is why I started keeping an archive of all of Apple's developer tools about 5 years ago. Good Luck.

Comment: Do you know if there's a public archive of that stuff anywhere?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8798/discussion-between-mark-thalman-and-seva-alekseyev)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest Xcode, you can install device debugging support via the Downloads->Components section, a la: http://cl.ly/3U1V1G3W2p2E1G29342e

Comment: That's *device* debugging support, right? Not the same as a simulator image? Still requires a 3.1 device?

Comment: Ah, yep - you're right. Thanks Seva. So not helping there unfortunately.